# Closing PySide Window terminates entire program

Tags: python, pyside

suppose I have a class which at some point in time will need to open a GUI, provided through a PySide implementation.

For example (and simplified) it could be looking something like this:

```py
class MyBackgroundClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #init stuff
    def open_gui(self):
        self.gui = MyGui()
```

At some point in time the method `open_gui()` will be called, which should initialize the GUI, which is implemented somehow like this:

```py
class MyGui():
    def __init__(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = MainWindow()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In this case `MainWindow` is another class which adds all elements to the GUI, which is not important here.
So basically `MyGUI` is just an implementation similar to how you typically implement a PySide/PyQT GUI, by using a `QApplication` and using `sys.exit(app.exec())`.

My Problem is, that because of `sys.exit`, the program termiantes completely when the GUI is closed, which is not what I want. I need the GUI to close when requested, but the main program `MyBackgroundClass` in this example needs to *keep running*.

I don't really know how to solve this problem.

**This is my first attempt:**

I tried removing `sys.exit(app.exec())` which led to following behaviour:

1. When I just run a script which opens the GUI, the GUI closes instantly.
2. But when I run my background script and create an instance of my GUI class, the GUI opens just fine.
   I think this is the case because in the second case, the GUI is not the main program.

I tried using `self.destroy()` and `self.close()` (where `self` refers to an object of the `MainWindow` class -> see init of MyGUI class) to close the GUI, because I am not using `sys.exit(app.exec())` anymore, which worked to some extend:

I was able to open and then close the GUI without any problems, but when I tried to *reopen* the GUI, this error occurred:

```py
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
RuntimeError: Please destroy the QApplication singleton before creating a new QApplication instance.
```

So the program fails when it tries to open the GUI again after it has been opened once, because there is still a QApplication which was not destroyed. The problem is, I don't know how to destroy the `QApplication` (in my case called "app"), because `self.destroy()` and `self.close()` only close the *window*, which is called "self.window" in my case.
Normally the QApplication would be destroyed when the program terminates, because of `sys.exit(app.exec())`. But because of the reasons above, `sys.exit(app.exec())` had to be removed.

**My solution (for now):**

Because I cant create another `QApplication` when there already is one because of the error above, I came up with this solution for `MyGui`:

```py
class MyGui():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self.window = MainWindow()
```

So I basically just removed `sys.exit(app.exec())` (because of the reasons above) and added a try/except block. The try/except block tries to create a `QApplication`, which succeeds, when the GUI is opened for the first time, but fails when the GUI is *reopened*. Therefore, I wont get the error that there is still a `QApplication` which did not get destroyed. And I can still created my GUI without any problems, because, well, the `QApplication` *is* still there.

**Conclusion**

I did find this solution and it works just fine, but I am not satisfied with the result. Using the try/except block solved the problem for me, but is a very very bad way of solving this problem.

I hope I made myself clear and some of you have some other ideas to solve this problem in a more appropriate way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't need to exit when the Qt app quits, just call `app.exec()`. OTOH it's important to understand if the Qt application should actually keep running or if the window should be reusable.

Comment: You can use `QApplication.instance()` if one already exists btw.

Comment: if you don't want to exit, don't call `sys.exit()`...

Comment: Maybe use `show()`/`hide()`?

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I will post my answer below.

Comment: I solved it like this: ```QApplication.instance()``` was very helpful:
if not QApplication.instance():
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        else:
            app = QApplication.instance()

Comment: Oh, no foramtting. Well, thanks again to all of you :)